# Best Practices when handling forms and previews in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot application which is using Thymeleaf as the template engine.

I have a page with a form that asks users to fill a few fields out and supply a file. The user then submits the form (which is a bean-backed form), it is handled by a controller method annotated with `PostMapping`, called `uploadPreview`.

This method validates the form and file, then adds the processing results to the model to be presented to the user. The user is then directed to a page with these results and can 'Confirm' the upload to be persisted to a database.

However, what is the best practice for handling this situation? Some approaches I thought of:

- Add the entire form object to the model in `uploadPreview` and essentially recreate the form with hidden inputs which will be submitted when the user clicks 'Confrm'.
- Use session attributes to store the form data.

Are these the recommended approaches?